# reverse function does not change the url to request a different view, django

Tags: python, django, reverse

I have a form that a user fills and then clicks a button to submit, then it calls a transition page, to inform the user that the form was completed. The user can click a button to go back to the home page from the transition page.

I want to get rid of the transition page and go to the home page directly. The reverse function does not change the URL but renders the correct homepage template. However, the context data in the template does not get populated and I am assuming that the URL not changing causes that.

The homepage `urls.py` I include:

```
url(r'^(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', views.UserHomePageView.as_view() , 
                                              name='user-homepage'),
```

Example: the form URL is

```
localhost:8000/form/15/fill
```

After the form is submitted, I want it to redirect to

```
localhost:8000/home/3
```

from the view after form submission, I call

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('homepage:user-homepage', args=[userid]))
```

Comment: Please show the entire view.

Comment: "The reverse function does not change the URL but renders the correct homepage template" - this cannot possibly be true. If you redirect to another page, the URL changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
return redirect('home')
```

Comment: I tired using redirect and it did not work. Did you mean return redirect('homepage:user-homepage')? I also need to pass an argument for the user id.

Comment: return redirect('home', id=user.id )

Comment: I tried redirect('homepage:user-hompage', user_id=userid) and it did the same thing as reverse. It rendered the right template, but it seems like it is not getting the context data. Not sure if it is actually calling the UserHomePageView that the 'homepage:user-hompage' namespace is associated with.

Comment: redirect works just fine. My issue was with something else unrelated apparently. It was easier for me to use javascript to redirect the transition page after few seconds of delay.